# Error in UseMethod("filter_"): no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r

I really need help this one. Can't see to find what's wrong with this. Spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out.

These 2 sections are identical in format but second block of code gives me an error when first picture doesn't.

```
q1_part_2_data <- q1_part_1_data %>%
    group_by(campaign_id) %>%
    summarise(Total_Impressions = sum(Impressions), Total_Spent = sum(Spent)) %>%
    mutate(CPM = Total_Spent/ Total_Impressions*1000) %>%
    dplyr::filter(CPM == max(CPM)) %>%
    select(campaign_id)

q1_part_2_data
```

```
q2_part_a_data <- data %>%
    filter(Spent != 0) %>%
    mutate(ROAS = round((10 * Total_Conversion + 50 * Approved_Conversion) / Spent, 2)) %>%
    filter(interest == 15 |interest == 21 |interest == 101)

ggplot(data = q2_part_a_data, aes(x = factor(interest), y = ROAS, fill = factor(gender))) + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10() + ggtitle("Boxplot for ROAS grouped by gender") + labs(x = "Interest Id", y = "ROAS")
```

Error message:
Error in UseMethod("filter_"): no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: It is trying to use a different `filter()` then the one you want from dplyr. The first block works because you are explicitly telling it which function to use. I suspect you are loading a package after dplyr which is masking the function. Try loading dplyr last.